# How should I test python unbound method with mock?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have some python class

```
Class A(object):

    def __init__(self, dep1, dep2, *args, **kwargs):
        self.prop1 = dep1
        self.prop2 = dep2

    def method1(self):
        self.prop3 = self.prop1.make_action()
        return
```

I need to test A.method1 from class A.
This is how I do it:

```
import pytest
import mock

def test__method1():
    """Ensure prop3 has been set from a.prop1.make_action() returned value"""
    a = mock.MagicMock(spec=A)
    a.prop1 = mock.Mock()
    a.prop2 = mock.Mock()
    a.prop1.make_action.return_value = "val1"
    A.method1(a)
    assert a.prop1.make_action.call_count == 1
    assert a.prop3 == "val1"
```

Is it the best way to make tests like this one, or I do something wrong?
Added: 
Firstly I tried to call method1 like this:

```
a.method1 = A.method1
a.method1()
```

But it didn`t work.
And now I also need to mock *a.prop1* and *a.prop2* explicitly. But in some cases, If I don't set the *spec* property, I don't need to mock prop1 and prop2, they are already here. These are the reasons I've asked this question

Comment: Looks fine to me; what problems did you have? `prop2` could be left un-set altogether, as `A.method1` doesn't touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Now I make like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def instance_of_a():
    a = mock.Mock(A)
    a.prop1 = mock.Mock()
    a.prop2 = mock.Mock()
    a.prop1.make_action.return_value = "val1" 
    return a

def test__a_method1(instance_of_a):
    A.method1(instance_of_a)
    assert instance_of_a.prop1.call_count == 1
    assert instance_of_a.prop3 == "val1"
```